# Is it possible to switch between BLAS libraries without recompiling program?

Tags: c++, linux, blas, caffe, openblas

For example can I have [Atlas](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), [OpenBlas](http://www.openblas.net/), [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 at the same time and switch between them without recompiling [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)?

Comment: @Shai to benchmark different BLAS libs with Caffe.

Comment: that's an interesting task. If you reach any conclusions it would be nice if you share them here.

Comment: Use [FlexiBLAS](https://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/projects/flexiblas). It's been the default BLAS implementation in Fedora since October 2020. Ubuntu/Debian installation instructions https://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/2427308/flexiblas_install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you have to have them installed, and on Ubuntu/Debian issue command

```
update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
```

You'll get numbered list of alternatives and could switch between them easily

Link: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/LinearAlgebraLibraries

Comment: Another question what if I build OpenBlas in ordinary way and with flag USE_OPENMP=1 ? Can I switch between them ? i.e. can I switch between library modifications/versions?

Comment: @mrgloom yes, but they should be different packages, providing the same alternative. Then `update-alternatives` will know about them

Comment: But how can I build them as several packages? For example if I build OpenBlas from source via `make` and then `make install PREFIX=your_installation_directory1` and then I compile with `make USE_OPENMP=1` and `make install PREFIX=your_installation_directory2`, can `update-alternatives` find my builds in this folders or how can I install two different builds of the same lib in ubuntu's default lib directory via `make install` ?

Comment: @mrgloom no, I'm talking about Debian/Ubuntu .deb packages. Best way is to download debian source package, alter it and rebuild. Check instructions here https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage

Answer (score 6):

You could also do it without changing system wide settings, for example by adding the library you want to use to the `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables. The first library on this path will be the one used to resolve the symbols against.

For example, you could run with

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/blas/lib.so ./my_executable_using_caffe
```

You can see that this approach would be extremely useful as part of a benchmarking script for different implementations since it doesn't affect the benchmarking environment itself. For example (in bash):

```
my_libraries=/path/to/blas1.so /path/to/blas2.so

for lib in $my_libraries
do
  LD_PRELOAD=${lib} ./my_executable_using_caffe
done
```

This approach, based on dynamic linking, applies to any other *shared library* your program is compiled against.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. You just need to use dynamic library linking.
The `libblas.so.3` is a soft linking to `/etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3`
Which in turn points to the `BLAS` library implementation

For example if you installing `Atlas`  (`sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base`):

```
/usr/lib/libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
/etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3 -> /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
```

while after installing `Openblas` (`sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base`):

```
/usr/lib/libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
/etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3 -> /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
```

Of course you can use your own soft link to your library builds.

Comment: `ldconfig -p` gives me `libblas.so.3gf (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf` and 
 `libblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libblas.so` what is `libblas.so.3` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @mrgloom could you list which blas packages are installed?