# what is high performance version of LAPACK and BLAS?

Tags: lapack, blas

This [page](http://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/6.0/math/default.htm?turl=usingscalapacklapacklinpackandeispack.htm) of IMSL says

> To obtain improved performance we recommend linking with High
>   Performance versions of LAPACK and BLAS, if available.

What is High Performance versions of LAPACK and BLAS ?

Comment: for example Atlas library, OpenBlas, Intel MKL

Comment: @ctheo  Thank you so much

Comment: @ctheo and how do they compared to the standard Lapack and Blas? Did they modify the source code? Will they less robust than the standard Lapack and Blas?

Comment: they are optimized for the CPU architecture. The interface is exactly the same with standard `BLAS`. I would suggest to test them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of good implementations to pick from:

1. [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468378) is likely the best on Intel machines. It's not free though, so that may be a problem.
2. According to their [benchmark](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/faq), [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) compares quite well with Intel MKL and is free
3. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is also an option and has a largish (albeit old) [benchmark](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark) showing good performance on small matrices (though it's not technically a drop-in BLAS library)
4. [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/), [OSKI](http://bebop.cs.berkeley.edu/oski/related.html), [POSKI](http://bebop.cs.berkeley.edu/poski/) are examples of auto-tuned kernels which will claim to work on many architectures

Generally, it is quite hard to pick one of these without benchmarking because:

1. some implementations work better on different types of matrices. For example Eigen works better on matrices with small rank (100s)
2. some are optimised for specific architectures (e.g. Intel's)
3. in some cases the multithreading of the BLAS library may conflict with a multithreaded application (e.g. OpenBLAS)
4. developer's benchmarks may tend to emphasise cases which work better on their implementation.

I would suggest pick one or two of these libraries that apply for your use case and benchmark them for your particular application on your particular (or similar) machine.  This is quite easy to do [even after compiling your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873211/is-it-possible-to-switch-between-blas-libraries-without-recompiling-program/33888750#33888750).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing rich information!

Comment: And cuBLAS is the most performant.

Answer (score -2):

LAPACK and BLAS are performance libraries that provides basically Linear Algebra mathematical operations for a system of linear equations. you can find such libraries useful in the computer vision for example ( Object detection and classifications ) , Classical algorithms, Modelling , ...

TAsking provides a full C implementation of the LAPACK and BLAS performance libraries, both libraries are ISO-C99 Compliant with full documentation and examples, you can check it here 
http://www.tasking.com/products/tasking-lapack-performance-libraries